# Validating certificates in client

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

When validating the certificate passed by server in the client, I see below first piece of code where a chain is created using the passed certificate leading up to the Root certificate and comparing the hash of it with the localCertificate.

Second block of code doesn't build the chain but simply loops through the ChainElements to get the Root certificate and compare the certificate's data with local certificate's data.

Why is second approach worse than the first?

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SSLPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {    
        X509Chain verify = new X509Chain();
        verify.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(localCertificate);
        verify.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        verify.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
        if(verify.Build(certificate))
        {
         var isSignedByCorrectRootCert = chain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement> 
                                         ().Last().Certificate.Thumbprint ==localCertificate.Thumbprint;
        }
    
    }


    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SSLPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
      foreach(var element in chain.ChainElements)
      { 
       foreach(var status in element.ChainElementStatus)
       {
        if(status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
        {
          if(localCertificate.GetRawCertDataString() == element.Certificate.GetRawCertDataString())
         {
           isValid = true;
           return true;
         }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: who said that 2nd approach is worse? What arguments they used to backup this statement?

Comment: Second approach could be be susceptible to forged certificate since it’s not recreating the Root from the given certificate using X509Chain?